# Check and obtain Server access using Windows Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking

First of all I'm a complete noob to Batch scripting and networking, with that being said, Here is what I'm trying to accomplish.
I want to check if the server has provided this batch file executing pc to access it, if not create access to it. (many different pc's run this batch file)
This what I came up with for now in my batch file.

```
net use * \\ip\My_WebApp /Persistent:yes /user:Username Password
Exit
```

This batch file command create access to the server just fine but It creates a new access connection every time this file get executed. Which is not needed and might crash the server load.

How can I check if the Server already has provided the access, Only if not, execute the above command in a batch file. my logic like like....

```
boolean status = check_server_accessibility()
if(!status){
   net use * \\ip\My_WebApp /Persistent:yes /user:Username Password
}
Exit
```

Appreciate any help, Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only ever need to perform the task once, which suggests that a scripted solution isn't needed, *(persistent means that!)*. I would assume that the following may be sufficient:

```bat
@Set "MyMap=\\ip\My_WebApp"
@%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe LogicalDisk Where "DriveType='4'" Get ProviderPath 2>NUL | %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /R /I "%MyMap:\=\\%\>" 1>NUL && GoTo :EOF
@%__AppDir__%net.exe Use * "%MyMap%" /Persistent:Yes /User:Username Password
```

Alternatively, if you needed to know which drive letter is currently assigned to it, then use a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) to retrieve the data:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

Call :MapChk "\\ip\My_WebApp"

GoTo :EOF

:MapChk
Set "MyMap=%~1"
Set "MyDrv="
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=:" %%G In (
    '%__AppDir__%wbem\WMIC.exe LogicalDisk Where "DriveType='4' And ProviderPath='%MyMap:\=\\%'" Get DeviceID 2^>NUL'
) Do For %%H In (%%G) Do Set "MyDrv=%%G:"
If Defined MyDrv (
    Echo %MyMap% is already mapped to drive %MyDrv%.
    %__AppDir__%timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak >NUL
    GoTo :EOF
)
%__AppDir__%net.exe Use * "%MyMap%" /Persistent:Yes /User:Username Password
```

I've made this one into a `call`able label, so that you can more easily extend it for other mappings too, e.g. before the `GoTo :EOF`, *(line `6`)*, `Call :MapChk "\\Server\My Share"`.

***Note:*** These solutions are untested, I do not use a PC and have no mapped network locations to test them against. Please let me know if I have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I forgot to inform that (edited Now), batch file will be executed by many PC's. Each of them checks the condition. and even one pc execute this batch file many many times.